# Django - Confirmation on first visit

Tags: python, django, cookies

In my new django project, I want the visitors to confirm the terms and condition before visiting a specific site, but this should only happen on the first time they visit the site. They don't have to be logged in, I will have to do this with cookies I think. Any ideas?

Comment: Django has [anonymous sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/), you can store some flag there to indicate, that user has confirmed terms.

Answer (score 1):

If you google for `django cookie law` you'll find several different options.

One of these options is [django-cookie-law](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-cookie-law).